# Letter with moderncv: how to include title in intestation but not in signature

Tags: moderncv, letters

When writing a letter with the `moderncv` class, how can one include an academic title in the "sender's intestation", but not in the signature?

The reverse question (adding title in signature but not in intestation) is already covered here: [adding educational title to moderncv letter signature](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514131/adding-educational-title-to-moderncv-letter-signature)

---

Minimal code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{black} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}


% sender's information data
\name{John}{Doe}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}

% recipient's information
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}

%letter info
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear TEX SE,}
\closing{Sincerely,}
\enclosure[Attached]{some attachment}

%document    
\begin{document}

\makelettertitle

I would like to have ``Dr. John Doe'' written in the sender's information displayed in the top right of the letter, but just ``John Doe'' in the signature at the end. Thanks!

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: @Mensch The naive approach of including the title in the \name. But this produced it also in the signature